# Load image in CustomListIem cell

Tags: list, sapui5

I´m trying to populate a CustomListItem cell in SAPUI5 with an image from my project´s source folder, but it is not showing on the cell. It is placed directly in the WebContent folder: App/WebContent/TEST.jpg, and the view code:

```
<Page title="View" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onBack">
    <content>
        <CustomListItem type="Inactive">
            <Image src="{TEST.jpg}" class="content" />
            <Button text="Press me!" class="content" />
        </CustomListItem>
    </content>
</Page>
```

the button is being shown in the first cell of the list (where the image should be), but not the image, does anyone know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the url path in the src property. If you enclose it in the brackets ({}), SAPUI5 expects a property binding path which in you case is invalid.

So replace this,

```
<Image src="{TEST.jpg}"
```

with

```
<Image src="TEST.jpg"
```